# iOS 12 UILabel in Xib not being displayed

Tags: ios

I have a simple xib file with a UILabel inside it.
Using auto layout I have placed the label (20, 15, 15, 10).

It appears appropriately on all prior iOS versions. However that label isn't being displayed in iOS 12.

I've tried deleting it and putting it back in again but it is still not being displayed.

Opening up the visual debugger doesn't show the UI Label although I can see it in the root hierarchy.

Comment: You will have to provide more information about the contents of the label, what constraints are set on the label etc.  Overall it sounds like the height or width of the label is being set to 0.

Comment: I have tried setting a height to the label bu that didn't solve it. I had to create a separate container to get it to work.